# Does windows installed via bootcamp only have access to the partitioned part of the HD?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

If I have a resized OS X partition of 500GB on my 750GB HD (250GB unallocated free space), and I install Windows 7 through bootcamp on a 300GB partition, can I partition the 250GB free space on my HD from Windows? or can I only work with the 300GB that was partitioned for it through bootcamp?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new partition within Windows 7, windows can see the whole disk, it can even access the files from you OS X partition using tools such as [Paragon HFS+](http://www.paragon-software.com/fr/home/hfs-windows/)